# Create Drupal SPARQL view from custom store?

Tags: drupal-7, rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I'm trying to create a Drupal 7 SPARQL view using my own store. I have the triples loaded in Virtuoso and in Fuseki but can't seem to make the final connection feeding a View. I am able to query the data successfully from the Fuseki and Virtuoso SPARQL UIs, just can't figure out how to define the Endpoint URI and Dataset so they combine properly  to form the SPARQL query that Drupal can use. For instance, it seems that Fuseki embeds the default dataset in the SPARQL endpoint URI (i.e., http://myhostname:3030/default/sparql) while Virtuoso doesn't.

Example data:

```
@prefix e1: <http://example.com/source/work/dataset/gov/vocab/enhancement/1/> .

e1:author a rdf:Property ;
    ov:csvCol "8"^^xsd:integer ;
    ov:csvHeader "author" ;
    conversion:enhancement_layer "1" ;
    dcterms:isReferencedBy <http://example.com/source/work/dataset/gov/version/2011-Aug-18/conversion/enhancement/1> ;
    rdfs:label "author" ;
    rdfs:range rdfs:Literal ;
    conversion:enhances raw:author .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataset field probably isn't what you want to use for this. You should put the full URI of the endpoint into the Endpoint URI field.

Feel free to post any other issues on the [SPARQL Views issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/sparql_views?categories=All), I don't spend much time on stackoverflow.

Comment: thanks linclark -- will head on over to the issue queue if I can't work it out.